# OpenCV VideoCapture and error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Tags: python, opencv

Currently using Windows 10 with Python 3.7
I tried running with this code in order to get the webcam to function for use in number recognition

```
def get_img_contour_thresh(img):
   x, y, w, h = 0, 0, 300, 300
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
   ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(blur, 175, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + 
     cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
   thresh1 = thresh1[y:y + h, x:x + w]
   contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
     cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
   return img, contours, thresh1

def show_webcam(mirror=False):
   # load json and create model
   json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
   loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
   json_file.close()
   model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
   # load weights into new model
   model.load_weights("model.h5")
   print("Loaded model from disk")

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    img, contours, thresh = get_img_contour_thresh(img)
    ans = ''


    if len(contours) > 0:
        contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 500:
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            newImage = thresh[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            newImage = cv2.resize(newImage, (28, 28))
            newImage = np.array(newImage)
            newImage = newImage.astype('float32')
            newImage /= 255

            if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
                newImage = newImage.reshape(1, 28, 28)
            else:
                newImage = newImage.reshape(28, 28, 1)
            newImage = np.expand_dims(newImage, axis=0)
            ans = model.predict(newImage).argmax()


    x, y, w, h = 0, 0, 300, 300
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(img, "CNN : " + str(ans), (10, 320),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", img)
    cv2.imshow("Contours", thresh)     


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def main():
   show_webcam(mirror=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

I receive this error

```
 File "cam.py", line 75, in <module>
   main()
 File "cam.py", line 71, in main
   show_webcam(mirror=True)
 File "cam.py", line 34, in show_webcam
   img, contours, thresh = get_img_contour_thresh(img)
 File "cam.py", line 10, in get_img_contour_thresh
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.4) C:\projects\opencv- 
   python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion 
   failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Iv been looking for a solution for a while but havent had any luck in figuring this out, tried looking around but just cant figure it out, what do you guys think? Appreciate the help given

Comment: chek your camera and sure that it was connected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error you're seeing is one that happens if `None` gets passed on `cv2.cvtColor`.

After

```
ret, img = cap.read()
```

it's a good idea to check that `img is not None` before proceeding. Depending on your input source, `cap.read()` can fail. On one my laptops, it fails at least once before starting to return valid images.

Comment: it's a better idea to check `if not ret: break` instead. that is what it's for. and it's also a good idea to check `cap.isOpened()` once after creating the VideoCapture instance