# my code is not working i am trying to make a hand operated game but showing error

Tags: python, opencv, cvzone

here is MY code:

```
import math
import random
import cvzone
import cv2
import numpy as np
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
cap.set(3, 1280)
cap.set(4, 720)

detector = HandDetector(detectionCon=0.8, maxHands=1)


class SnakeGameClass:
    def __init__(self, pathFood):
        self.points = []  # all points of the snake
        self.lengths = []  # distance between each point
        self.currentLength = 0  # total length of the snake
        self.allowedLength = 150  # total allowed Length
        self.previousHead = 0, 0  # previous head point

        self.imgFood = cv2.imread(pathFood, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        self.hFood, self.wFood, _ = self.imgFood.shape
        self.foodPoint = 0, 0
        self.randomFoodLocation()

        self.score = 0
        self.gameOver = False

    def randomFoodLocation(self):
        self.foodPoint = random.randint(100, 1000), random.randint(100, 600)

    def update(self, imgMain, currentHead):

        if self.gameOver:
            cvzone.putTextRect(imgMain, "Game Over", [300, 400],
                               scale=7, thickness=5, offset=20)
            cvzone.putTextRect(imgMain, f'Your Score: {self.score}', [300, 550],
                               scale=7, thickness=5, offset=20)
        else:
            px, py = self.previousHead
            cx, cy = currentHead

            self.points.append([cx, cy])
            distance = math.hypot(cx - px, cy - py)
            self.lengths.append(distance)
            self.currentLength += distance
            self.previousHead = cx, cy

            # Length Reduction
            if self.currentLength > self.allowedLength:
                for i, length in enumerate(self.lengths):
                    self.currentLength -= length
                    self.lengths.pop(i)
                    self.points.pop(i)
                    if self.currentLength < self.allowedLength:
                        break

            # Check if snake ate the Food
            rx, ry = self.foodPoint
            if rx - self.wFood // 2 < cx < rx + self.wFood // 2 and \
                    ry - self.hFood // 2 < cy < ry + self.hFood // 2:
                self.randomFoodLocation()
                self.allowedLength += 50
                self.score += 1
                print(self.score)

            # Draw Snake
            if self.points:
                for i, point in enumerate(self.points):
                    if i != 0:
                        cv2.line(imgMain, self.points[i - 1], self.points[i], (0, 0, 255), 20)
                cv2.circle(imgMain, self.points[-1], 20, (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)

            # Draw Food
            imgMain = cvzone.overlayPNG(imgMain, self.imgFood,
                                        (rx - self.wFood // 2, ry - self.hFood // 2))

            cvzone.putTextRect(imgMain, f'Score: {self.score}', [50, 80],
                               scale=3, thickness=3, offset=10)

            # Check for Collision
            pts = np.array(self.points[:-2], np.int32)
            pts = pts.reshape((-1, 1, 2))
            cv2.polylines(imgMain, [pts], False, (0, 255, 0), 3)
            minDist = cv2.pointPolygonTest(pts, (cx, cy), True)

            if -1 <= minDist <= 1:
                print("Hit")
                self.gameOver = True
                self.points = []  # all points of the snake
                self.lengths = []  # distance between each point
                self.currentLength = 0  # total length of the snake
                self.allowedLength = 150  # total allowed Length
                self.previousHead = 0, 0  # previous head point
                self.randomFoodLocation()

        return imgMain


game = SnakeGameClass("Donut.png")

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    hands, img = detector.findHands(img, flipType=False)

    if hands:
        lmList = hands[0]['lmList']
        pointIndex = lmList[8][0:2]
        img = game.update(img, pointIndex)
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('r'):
        game.gameOver = False
```

i am getting error in line: `hands, img = detector.findHands(img, flipType=False)`

error showing as:

```
       File "c:\py\Snake game\main.py", line 108, in <module>
   hands, img = detector.findHands(img, flipType=False)
 File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cvzone\HandTrackingModule.py", line 48, in findHands
   imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [imread returns None, violating assertion !\_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676020/imread-returns-none-violating-assertion-src-empty-in-function-cvtcolor-er)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV VideoCapture and error: (-215:Assertion failed) !\_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121013/opencv-videocapture-and-error-215assertion-failed-src-empty-in-function)

Comment: i am not getting solution help me with correct code

Comment: @ankitkumar As per the questions that are linked in these comments, you need to make sure that `cap.read()` actually gives you an image and not just `None`. There is nothing wrong with the code *per se*, but the function is not behaving as you expect. The answer that Christoph links to is that `cap.read()` can fail.

Comment: all of the above are correct:  success, img = cap.read() => `False` , `None` so img=`None`. This is the point of fail.

Comment: What I do for cap.read() gives an image I didn't understand

Comment: @eandklahn how to solve the error

Answer (score 0):

Actually there was problem in `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)`
replace it with `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`
now my code is working fine...