# cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using OpenCV to create a color mask of all the red pixels on the screen and I'm facing an issue where simply 'hsv' has an empty src I think but I'm not sure

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1000)

while(1):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   
    lower_red = np.array([30,150,50])
    upper_red = np.array([255,255,180])
   
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)
    
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)
   
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

The error I keep getting is:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "index.py", line 8, in <module> hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'`

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV VideoCapture and error: (-215:Assertion failed) !\_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121013/opencv-videocapture-and-error-215assertion-failed-src-empty-in-function)

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour] and review [ask]. you should have searched for the error before asking.

Comment: This error occurs because the tutorial you've taken your code from does not do proper error checking. Please go back and ask the author of the tutorial to correct their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error happens because it can't open your camera. The integer you pass to `VideoCapture()` is the camera id, if you just pass '0' it will open the default camera. Other than that, make sure to allow apps to use your camera in privacy settings.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

[Reference](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a5d5f5dacb77bbebdcbfb341e3d4355c1)

Comment: That results in this error:VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 8, in <module>
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'

Comment: Could try with index `-1`?

Comment: It says cant find camera device

Comment: @Frickling Try this then: `cv2.VideoCapture(0, CAP_V4L2)`

Comment: Getting closer! it says: NameError: name 'CAP_V4L2' is not defined

Comment: @Frickling Right, sorry it should be `cv2.CAP_V4L2`.

Comment: now it says cant open camera by index

Comment: @Frickling Just to make sure you can turn your camera on manually, right?

Comment: yea, I can. I actually have problems with my camera opening and it opens only under certain circumstances but currently I can open it with other apps