# Error while trying to get video from webcam with OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

OS: Win7
Python version: updated (3.8.1)
So the thing is, by using **OpenCV module**
, I'm trying to access the inbuilt webcam of my laptop to capture the video & process the frames, but the window displating the real-time video is not showing up despite the indicator light of the webcam turning on implying the webcam is working, and the following error is being encountered:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File:............. line 8, in 
> gray = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'> Blockquote

Here's the code snippet:

```
import cv2
import winsound
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
while cam.isOpened():
    ret, frame1 = cam.read()
    ret, frame2 = cam.read()
    diff = cv2.absdiff(frame1, frame2)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

Comment: always the same, `assert cam.isOpened()` right after its creation, and `if not ret: break` after each read

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV VideoCapture and error: (-215:Assertion failed) !\_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121013/opencv-videocapture-and-error-215assertion-failed-src-empty-in-function)

Comment: Change this:  grey = cv2.cvtColor(d, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)